# (English, Perl, Python, Ruby) comparison on a code fragment-by-fragment basis?

Tags: python, ruby, perl, comparison

Looking for a code samples that present a code fragment in plain English, Perl, Python, and Ruby. Here's an [example](http://williamjxj.wordpress.com/2010/11/27/perl-vs-python-vs-ruby/) of a whole mini-solution present in that format, but I'd rather just have the code present in a fragment-by-fragment basis.

Comment: [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Welcome_to_Rosetta_Code)

Comment: @aaronasterling: That's the best answer, please post it as such so we can upvote :)

Comment: People write crap in Perl and then complain it is not very readable. CICO.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür: I agree, though the whole "crap in crap out" becomes part of a language at some point; meaning good coders leave, and only those that no nothing about coding join in; no idea if this applies to Perl, but if it does, it's very possible that this may be traced to the "more than one way" mantra.

Comment: Well, the guy you give as an example wrote ugly code and complained about it being ugly and chose it as a reason to leave Perl. I say self-selection is working.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür: Just wondering, what to you make of the Perl 6 syntax? http://perlcabal.org/syn/Differences.html

Comment: btw this is kind of unrelated but i think it deserves and mention more or less whenever language comparison is being discussed - http://codepad.org/

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder, but here's my take on the code in your example: http://blog.nu42.com/2010/12/dont-blame-perl-for-all-ugly-code.html

Comment: @Sinan Ünür: Great, thank you -- was going to ask, but thought that would be too much. I'll take a look at it later today when I've got time; on my way to work. By the way, what do you think of these series of books for learning Perl? series of books: http://www.theperlreview.com/training.html Anything you would add online, or via another book? Cheers!

Comment: Those are fine books. I have them all. However, I learned what I learned by reading the documentation that comes with Perl and Perl modules, a lot of trial and error, asking questions and trying to answer others' questions. I am no expert in Ruby or Python, but I believe they are equally capable languages compared to Perl (although, Perl's Unicode support seems to be way ahead of theirs at the moment). I have grown really fond of sigils and CPAN has saved me countless hours and provided generous returns on my investment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Rosetta Code**](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Welcome_to_Rosetta_Code) currently has 449 tasks, of which some 349 languages are covered, though the site does not (and cannot) promise to have solutions to every task in every language.

**NOTE:** [aaronasterling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/376728/aaronasterling) posted Rosetta Code as a comment to the question, but never as an answer. After 24-hours, posted it as an answer myself, since I'm not planning on leaving my question open forever, and it's an answer to the question. Feel free to up vote the comment, and not this answer; if aaronasterling post it as an answer, I'll delete this answer.

Answer (score 2):

A good place to look would be [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) where (after solving the puzzles yourself) you get access to solutions by other people in all kinds of programming languages. Of course, sometimes there will be atrocious solutions, so you'd have to look at the answers carefully.

Comment: ... albeit that's most math-related problems.

Comment: @delnan: Knowing nothing about math, I in fact find it interesting that mathematical notation could be a replacement for English in the context of this question; in part based on my assumption that mathematical notation is universal across languages.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: +1 Thanks, given it's not an extact match my request for a comparison of just the covered languages on a fragment-by-fragment basis (without having to code an answer) going to wait and see if anyone else answers. If not, I'll select you as the answer. Again, thanks!

Comment: @blunders: But depending on what you want (just basic syntax comparision, or actually see idioms etc.), it could be a con that most programs on Project Euler fall into a few categories. For example, I don't think there is any problem over there that requires file I/O. For seeing many different tasks implemented in many different programming languages, see Rosetta Code.

Comment: @delnan: Yes, I agree, but nothing's every going to be perfect, in this case readability related to cross referencing the sample at hand is the biggest thing to me. I'm 100% sure there differences in the implementations of the compilers, syntax, etc. that might make some problems impossible, or non-effective in one language or another. Just focused on the core syntax and idiomatic expression in a given language.

Comment: you do see a weird selection of languages on project euler.  ie - theres an oddly high proportion of assembly lang coders and a few guys using J or K (they are like APL, the even 'less mainstream' flavor of FP, and its 'tacit' composition of functions is really cool)  There are Python, Ruby, C, Java and JS coders among the mix but the fact that the problems fall in one particular niche with many aspects totally absent (db access, gui/graphics, network, user input, etc) make it an, at beast, incomplete reference for language comparison (Plus you have to beat a problem before seeing its forum!)